# Append Values to CSV and retain the old data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have to append the data in CSV, the problem I am facing is intead of appending I am overwriting the data, not able to retain the old data, example :

```
finalDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sourcez', 'tergetz', 'TMP'])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["sourcez"] = ["str(source_Path)"]
df["tergetz"] = ["str(target_path)"]
df["TMP"] = ["total_matching_points"]
finalDf = finalDf.append(df)
finalDf.to_csv('Testing.csv', index=False)
```

Now if I add a new value

```
finalDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sourcez', 'tergetz', 'TMP'])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["sourcez"] = ["str(source_Path)_New"]
df["tergetz"] = ["str(target_path)_New"]
df["TMP"] = ["total_matching_points_New"]
finalDf = finalDf.append(df)
finalDf.to_csv('Testing.csv', index=False)
```

It is keeping the latest data in csv instead I want both data to be updated in csv. any idea?

I have tried to create a new csv with pandas dataframe and I want to append the values instead overwriting
I have tried:

```
finalDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sourcez', 'tergetz', 'TMP'])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["sourcez"] = ["str(source_Path)"]
df["tergetz"] = ["str(target_path)"]
df["TMP"] = ["total_matching_points"]
finalDf = finalDf.append(df)
finalDf.to_csv('Testing.csv', index=False, mode='a+')
```

But the problem is heading is repeating csv:

**sourcez,tergetz,TMP**

str(source_Path),str(target_path),total_matching_points

**sourcez,tergetz,TMP**

str(source_Path)_New,str(target_path)_New,total_matching_points_New

How to remove repeated headings **sourcez,tergetz,TMP**

Comment: please share sample of your data so the issue can be reproduced

Comment: it's like I have a df where we have 3 columns ['sourcez', 'tergetz', 'TMP'] and we have a temp df where we are stroing some string and if we run the same it will store all the values and I need to remove the heading that is repeating :
exmapl o/p I am getting
sourcez,tergetz,TMP
 str(source_Path),str(target_path),total_matching_points 
sourcez,tergetz,TMP str(source_Path)_New,str(target_path)_New,total_matching_points_New

where heading : sourcez,tergetz,TMP is repeating on every updation of csv how to geting heading only one time

Comment: the problem is with the line finalDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sourcez', 'tergetz', 'TMP']), once you saved the new csv in disk you need to read it back and after that to append